# Select main divs neglecting child div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want that on selecting the outer divs of both the container, my alert function should work without using any id's or class name.

Basically what I need is if I have 4 main divs having any no of children. I should be able to add some event to all outermost div only no matter how many child divs it has. Is this possible?

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0];
x.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target == this) {
    alert('Outermost Div');
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.first-div {
  padding: 15px;
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 70%;
}

.first-div-child {
  padding: 15px;
  background: red;
}

.first-div-child>p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-div">
    <div class="first-div-child">
      <p> This is Para </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="first-div">
    <div class="first-div-child">
      <p> This is Para </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to add the event listener to the outer div's by selecting them by means of their ClassName. This would be able to solve your current issue

```
        <script>
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
        x.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
            if(e.target == this) {
                alert('Outermost Div');
            }
        })


    </script>
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Select the `div`s by class name instead of tag name. This will return an `[HTML Collection]` containing all the outer `div`'s that you can convert into a true array and use the `forEach` method to set your event listeners up. You can compare the `event.currentTarget` to the `event.target` and alert if they are equal. See below code snippet:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
[...x].forEach( node => node.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.currentTarget === e.target) console.log('outerMostDiv');
}));
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.first-div {
  padding: 15px;
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 70%;
}

.first-div-child {
  padding: 15px;
  background: red;
}

.first-div-child>p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-div">
    <div class="first-div-child">
      <p> This is Para </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="first-div">
    <div class="first-div-child">
      <p> This is Para </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The className container is for testing purpose. I want the logic to be generic. If I am running that logic in any live website all the main divs should be fetched irrespective of the structure